# Cannot assign a value of type 'MyViewController' to a value of type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextviewdelegate

Not sure why I am getting this error (title of this issue is the error as shown in screenshot below) when I try to do `self.tv_salaryNumber.delegate = self`.

My class `EarningsVC` does in fact inherit the [UITextFieldDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/), so cant figure out why getting this error. (You can see that on the right most part of hte window under `Quick Help` too.

[image]

Comment: remove "self" from the textfeild use it as tv_salaryNumber.delegate = self and use TextFeildDelegate instead TextViewDelegate

Comment: @FattiKhan that isnt probably needed either, but i had a more silly error. added that as answer (hate to answer my own question but this was a silly one, thanks for your time)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question but found my (silly) error right after I posted this. I was adding `UITextViewDelegate` instead of `UITextFieldDelegate` - so had the wrong delegate.

Comment: lol... 10 minutes of staring at this compiler error for my own code later... I see that I used 'View' also... ;)!!!...